NoReverseMatch at /users/reset/done/

this is my url file  after getting link on terminal and typing new password i am getting this message when i hit to submit, eventually password is reset but i am getting the error NoReverseMatch at /users/reset/done/
i tried without using templates and with custom templates of my own    this is a github link of project  https://github.com/agrawalaman4310/Social_Project.git

Issue is with your login url.
In settings.py file update the login and logout url like this
LOGIN_URL='login'
LOGOUT_URL='logout'


i already done this

If it worked, kindly accept the answer
